# Is the Laplace transform a vector space isomorphism? And what space is it isomorphic to?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, laplace-transform, linear-transformations

The laplace transform is a linear transformation, $\mathcal{L}: \mathcal{M} \rightarrow?$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is the set of exponentially bounded functions on $\mathbb{R},$since $\mathcal{L}(af(x)+bg(x))=a \mathcal{L}(f(x))+b\mathcal{g(x)}$   for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g \in \mathcal{M}$. 
It seems to be injective since $\operatorname{Ker}(\mathcal{L})=0$ unless I've missed something. Therefore by the rank-nullity theorem $\mathcal{L}$ must surjective and so it is an isomorphism. So my questions are 1) Is this proof outline correct? and 2) what set is the laplace transform mapping into?

Comment: I don't really see how that's helpful. If it's an isomorphism then it must be homomorphism by definition. The question is more less regarding the set into which the laplace transform maps.

Comment: I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390157/a-very-simple-question-what-spaces-of-function-does-the-laplace-transform-map-f

Comment: Also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_square#On_the_half-plane

Comment: Just a quick comment. Be careful when you try to apply rank-nullity to infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace transform does not have kernel zero and is not injective on the domain you have specified. In particular, if $f$ and $g$ differ at countably many points they will have the same Laplace transform. Using the same approach as is typically used to define $L^2$, we can define $\mathcal{M}'$ to be the quotient space produced by quotenting out by "having the same Laplace Transform." However I do not know a nice way to describe $\mathcal{M}'$. In either case, I am also unsure what the range is. You may be interested in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_square#On_the_half-plane) which provides the range when the domain is $L^2(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

- If $F(s)$ is analytic on $\Re(s) > c$ and  $L^2$ on vertical lines  and as $\Im(s) \to \pm \infty$, $F(s) \to 0$ uniformly on strips $\Re(s) \in [u,v]$
  then let
  $$f_{\sigma,T}(x)= \frac1{2\pi} \int_{-T}^T F(\sigma+it) e^{itx}dt, \qquad x\in \Bbb{R} $$

  - (From Parseval theorem for the Fourier  transform) $\lim_{T \to \infty}f_{\sigma,T}$ converges in $L^2(\Bbb{R})$
  - (From Cauchy integral formula) the limit is $e^{-\sigma x}f$ for some function $f$ independent of $\sigma>c$.
- If also $$\lim_{\sigma \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |F(\sigma+it)|^2dt = 0$$
  then $f$ vanishes on $(-\infty,0)$.
- Conversely if $f$ is supported on $[0,\infty)$ and $f e^{-c x} \in L^2$ for some $c$ then $f e^{-\sigma x}$ is $L^1$ for $ \sigma >c$, its Laplace transform $$F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx}dx$$ is well-defined for $\Re(s) > c$ and it satisfies the above properties.
- If $F$ is $L^1$ on some vertical line then $fe^{-\sigma x}$ is not only bounded but also uniformly continuous. I don't think there is any easy way to ensure from $F$ that $f e^{-\sigma x}$ is only bounded for some $\sigma$.